# Does anybody know an embedded software library or embedded software development framework?

Tags: embedded, firmware

My company is about to replace the 8 bit microcontrollers in all our embedded devices with ARM Cortex-M controllers (32 bit). We will need to redesign and clean up considerable parts of the existing firmware, because it is in pretty bad shape and cannot easily be ported to a different processor.

We do now plan to go for a clean architecture, so we do not need to throw away all the software again, when it needs to be integrated on yet another processor.

We already realized, that we need some basic software infrastructure and utility code (e. g. handling data in containers, logging, data storage in flash and EEPROM, …).

Does anybody know of a platform-independent embedded software library or embedded software development framework that provides basic functionality like this? I am sure others need this kind of infrastructure as well and I cannot believe that everybody is developing this functionality on its own. However, during my web research I did not find a suitable solution so far.

Comment: Such questions are generally considered off-topic on SO.  Frameworks that do exist tend to be fairly tightly coupled to specific architectures or reference designs.  [mbed](https://www.mbed.com/en/) for example might meet your requirements, but is Cortex-M specific.  [Keil's MDK-ARM](http://www.keil.com/arm/mdk.asp) is perhaps less tightly coupled to a specific hardware design and includes a lot of *middleware* components.

Comment: Why is that? I am aware of the frameworks you mention. My question is: Is there a more generic library / framework that is not specific to a certain hardware architecture? Jörg's answer suggests that this might be the case. However, I first need to take a closer look at redBlocks.

Comment: "Why is that?" is a matter of opinion, and a discussion for a forum rather then SO.  A generic library would require an adaptable hardware abstraction layer which might add unacceptable code-bloat to resource constrained targets, be sub-optimal performance-wise, and might not be able to utilise unique capabilities of specific targets.  It is the unique capabilities that are the hardware vendors selling points, so they would probably not appreciate a software architecture that makes the choice of processor irrelevant.

Comment: With "Why is that?" I was refering to "Such questions are generally considered off-topic on SO". I simply do not see why my original question should be off-topic. After h

Comment: After having looked in Jörg's proposal I think that this toolkit may be exactly what I am looking for: It actually includes an adaptable hardware abstraction layer, like you say. But it seems to avoid any code overhead.

Answer (score 2):

I recently worked as a consultant for a company here in Germany that faced pretty much the same situation. They decided to go for C++ as their programming language and used an embedded software library called redBlocks ([www.redblocks.de](http://www.redblocks.de)). It is platform independent and might be what you are looking for.

However, even though it is open source, it is a commercial product and they charge a license fee.

Comment: Thanks. It looks promising and I will take a closer look.