# Is C++ suited for tiny embedded targets?

Tags: c++, embedded, firmware

We are currently redesigning our embedded software and are going from 8 bit to 32 bit Cortex-M microcontrollers. Memory is pretty limited (128 kByte Flash and 32 kByte RAM). 
In [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645681/does-anybody-know-an-embedded-software-library-or-embedded-software-development) an embedded software library ([www.redblocks.de](http://www.redblocks.de)) was recommended. It seems to cover my needs very well, but requires the use of C++.
Does anybody have experience with C++ on embedded platforms like ours? I am wondering what kind of overhead I am dealing with, compared to C.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be too broad and opinion-based for this site. You might want to edit the question (or ask a new one) with a more narrow question, or with any particular problem you face or anticipate facing.

Comment: So far, I've programmed all cortex based mcs in C++ and didn't encounter any problems. Depending on how you manage your heap however, you might not be able to use STL containers or at least require your own allocator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the C++ features you are using, there is little to no overhead compared to C.

Here are some features compared:

- Using classes without virtual methods results in the same binary code
  as C functions working on a data structure that is passed along as a
  pointer
- When classes with virtual methods are used, a vptr is added to the object’s data section and a vtable introduced in the text memory segment. Similar functionality can be implemented in C with function pointers (that occupy memory as well). As soon as you have more than one virtual method in a class, you typically end up with more efficient binary code when using C++ instead of manually introducing  multiple function pointers per object with C.
- The efficiency of exception handling differs from compiler to compiler.
- RTTI adds overhead and should not be used on tiny embedded targets.
- Non-deterministic dynamic memory usage (malloc / free in C and new / delete in C++) should be avoided with both programming languages on platforms without virtual memory management.
- Templates have much in common with C preprocessor macros as they are evaluated during compile time and are a kind of compile time source code generation. Thus, they do not add any runtime overhead. However, using them non-deliberately will result in bloated code. If used in the right places, they can even help reducing runtime overhead.

I think the most challenging issue is the developers’ knowledge. C++, especially when using templates a lot, is a much more sophisticated language than C. So you need a bunch of pretty good developers.

However, if you want to go for a clean and reusable object oriented design, C++ is certainly the better choice than C.

Comment: Thanks for this excellent response.

Comment: Reinhard: yes, this is a great answer. You should click the check mark next to this answer to select it as the Accepted Answer to help @Mats increase his reputation score.

Answer (score 2):

I am not an embedded developer myself but I have several colleagues using c++ on the kind of microcontrollers you are targeting.

The language by itself does not add a lot of overhead but the use of the standard library (containers, algorithms...) is not recommended if you are limited in Flash/RAM.

If the performances are an issue you might also want to avoid RTTI and exception.

More information on [this paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/ESC_San_Jose_98_401_paper.pdf) or on [this page](http://www.embedded.com/design/programming-languages-and-tools/4424383/2/A-guide-to-C--for-C-programmers).

The book [Effective C++ in an Embedded Environment](http://www.artima.com/shop/effective_cpp_in_an_embedded_environment) form Scott Meyers is also a very good source of information.